# InstallShield Hash on files to be installed

Tags: installation, hash, installshield, checksum

I have an InstallShield project and I want to implement a hash / crc check like Microsoft has relating to MSICHECKCRCS. Is there someway in InstallShield to set some option that the file is hashed/checked before installation then hash/checked after installation to make sure the installation file was corrupted?
And if there is such an option what will InstallShield do if the file is corrupted?

Thank you

Comment: Which project you are using in Installshield? Basic MSI or InstallScript or anything else?

Comment: I am using InstallShield

Comment: Installshield is the tool name which is used to generate windows-installer, bootstrapper. I am asking for project type being used within installshield.

Comment: whoops typo, InstallScript project